# AwesomeWM - Error "__newindex " since got a new monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

I've been using AwesomeWM with a dual screen classic layout for few months.
I recently purchased a ultrawide screen and set my 2nd monitor as "portrait mode".

Since then, I got an error message when I boot on AwesomeWM :

```
An error happened !
/usr/share/awesome/lib/awful/rules.lua: 724: bad argument #-1 to '__newindex'  (screen expected, got nil)
```

My main ultrawide monitor is now black and my 2nd monitor is working altough it is working as a regular monitor despite being physically set as portrait mode.

I'm pretty new to AwesomeWM and struggling a bit with Lua. Can I get someone help me with this ? Should I set Xrandr to make both my awesomewm config and my monitors working ?

Cheers!

Comment: Hello, what is your awesome version? (you can use `awesome -v` in the command line)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The version is "4.3-5+b1" coming from the Debian Bulleyes official repo.

Comment: Do you think you can try to compile the latest git version? The Debian way is `apt build-dep awesome -y`, then you `git clone` our source code and run `make package` and install the `.deb`. I rewrote most of the code related to your problem, so it is probably already fixed.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. Question though, should I "apt remove --purge awesome" first from my system and then compile the latest git version ? or can I leave the current version and install the new one ? what's your recommendation ?

Comment: Where is this linked from (so I can fix the link)? As for the deps, `sudo apt install libxfixes-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev -y` seems to be the right one for debian.

Comment: The link comes from : 'https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome' , advanced options and testing , the "here" hyperlink.

Answer (score -1):

Check your rc.lua, i found rule that changes for TelegramDesktop screen property to 2 (This problem occurs only with telegram for me), and i deleted that rule, reloaded awesome and no errors!!